# Delete / Truncate table in Symfony 3.4 not working as it should

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to import data with Symfony 3.4. And I have successfully finished the task. In the end, I run into some problems, and I don't know how to solve it. So, what am I doing:

- taking data from an Excel file and store it in the database.
- on refresh, I delete the table and again go through the excel file and store values in the database

I just saw that primary keys are getting updated. It is not a problem, but it bothers me. So if I add 130 rows, delete them, store them again, the primary key will start from 260, and back from 390 and so on.

So I decided not to delete a table, but to truncate it. And the first time it creates 130 rows. On refresh, it truncates the table but stores only five rows instead of 130, and I cannot find the bug. So on delete everything works fine, but on truncate, the second time it stores only five rows instead of 130. Here is my code, and if someone sees the bug, please let me know:

```
public function importMappedAttributes($mappedAttributesValues)
{

    if (!$this->checkIfTableIsEmpty()) {
        $this->truncateTable();
    }

    try{

       foreach ($mappedAttributesValues as $value) {
            $mappedAttributes = new MappedAttribute();

            $mappedAttributes->setAkeneoAttribute($value['result_one']);
            $mappedAttributes->setXmlAttribute($value['result_two']);
            $mappedAttributes->setXmlPath($value['result_three']);
            $mappedAttributes->setMetadata($value['result_four']);

            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($mappedAttributes);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

        }
    } catch (\Exception $e){

        throw new \Exception('Something went wrong!');

    }
}
```

The first part checks if the table is empty and if is not truncate it:

```
private function checkIfTableIsEmpty() {

    $numberOfRows = count($this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('ImportAttributesBundle:MappedAttribute')->findAll());

    if ($numberOfRows > 1) {

        return false;

    }

    return true;
}

public function truncateTable() {
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $classMetaData = $em->getClassMetadata('ImportAttributesBundle:MappedAttribute');
    $connection = $em->getConnection();
    $dbPlatform = $connection->getDatabasePlatform();
    try {
        $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
        $q = $dbPlatform->getTruncateTableSql($classMetaData->getTableName());
        $connection->executeUpdate($q);
        $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
        $connection->commit();

    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        $connection->rollback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that $this->getEntityManager()->flush(); should go outside the foreach. That was causing unexpected behavior and when I put it after the foreach everything worked fine.